# How to get user data of Aave pool position inside of Solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, aave

I'm developing a smart contract, which deposits into Aave v3 stablecoin pools. For withdrawal, you have to specify the underlying token address of the a token (e..g usdc address, dai address, ...) and the amount of tokens to be withdrawn.

I want to call the on-chain aave pool contract to get the token amount eligible for withdrawal for every position (usdc, dai, ...). Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can query how much you can withdraw from an asset you supplied by querying your [`AToken`](https://docs.aave.com/developers/tokens/atoken) balance that represents your position for a specific token.

The `AToken` balance get minted when you call the `supply()` function and gets burnt when you call `withdraw()`. Simply query how much ATokens you have by calling the `balanceOf()` function and that will be the maximum amount of token you can withdraw.

The hard part part knowing the `AToken` address. You can get the address by calling the [`getReserveData()`](https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol#L582) function like this:

```
address aTokenAddress = IPool(AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS).getReserveData(STAKED_TOKEN_ADDRESS).aTokenAddress;
```

Where `AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS` is the [Aave Pool](https://docs.aave.com/developers/core-contracts/pool) Address, unique for each Aave deployment and `STAKED_TOKEN_ADDRESS` is the token address you supplied (DAI or USDC for example).

To call this you will need to add references to [DataTypes](https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/protocol/libraries/types/DataTypes.sol) library and to [IPool](https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol):

```
library DataTypes {
  struct ReserveConfigurationMap {
    uint256 data;
  }

  struct ReserveData {
    ReserveConfigurationMap configuration;
    uint128 liquidityIndex;
    uint128 currentLiquidityRate;
    uint128 variableBorrowIndex;
    uint128 currentVariableBorrowRate;
    uint128 currentStableBorrowRate;
    uint40 lastUpdateTimestamp;
    uint16 id;
    address aTokenAddress;
    address stableDebtTokenAddress;
    address variableDebtTokenAddress;
    address interestRateStrategyAddress;
    uint128 accruedToTreasury;
    uint128 unbacked;
    uint128 isolationModeTotalDebt;
  }
}

interface IPool {
    function getReserveData(
        address asset) external view returns (DataTypes.ReserveData memory);
}
```

Once you have the `AToken` address, you can know how much you're able to withdraw by calling the `balanceOf()` function. For example you can withdraw all your supplied tokens the following way, assuming the tokens were staked by the smart contract:

```
IPool(AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS).withdraw(
  IERC20(aTokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this)),
  amount,
  msg.sender
);
```